# JavaScript Draw a Rectangle When Screen is Pressed

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple application using JavaScript that draws a rectangle when I press the screen (On a touch screen). I don't know why it isn't working. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="drawingboard" width="500" height="500" style="border:10px solid #000000;">
    You have a horrible browser that will not support an HTML canvas, so this won't work.
</canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var c = document.getElementById("drawingboard");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var mouseDown = 0;
document.body.ontouchstart = function() { 
  mouseDown+=1;
}
document.body.ontouchend = function() {
  mouseDown-=1;
}
if (mouseDown == 1) {

ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);}
```

Comment: you need to draw in the event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jude, Replace the fillrect line with this:

```
   ctx.fillRect(event.clientX-50,event.clientY-50,100,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the complete ( but messy ) code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pixel Drawing</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas onclick=draw(event)
id="drawingboard" width="850" height="390" 
style="border:10px             
                          solid    plum;"> 

You have a horrible browser that will not support an HTML  
canvas, so this won't work.</canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("drawingboard");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var mouseDown = 0;
document.body.ontouchstart = function() { 
mouseDown+=1;
}
document.body.ontouchend = function() {
mouseDown-=1;
}
function draw(event){

ctx.color='gold';
ctx.fillStyle = "lime";
ctx.fillRect(event.clientX,event.clientY,100,100);}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks... What does the ctx.color="gold"; do? I know the fill style fills the rectangle but the gold color doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Also... When I tap the screen, it draws the rectangle to the right of where I tapped.